# AWS Lambda does not recognize log4j2.xml config file

Tags: java, logging, aws-lambda, log4j2

I'm trying to log in my aws lambda function with log4j2 Loggers, but unfortunately the log4j2.xml can't be found and I just see in the CloudTrail logs the standard error message

> "ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console."

If I run the application locally (call the object method in the main method) everything works fine). I followed the official AWS documentation but it didn't help.

The dummy project that can be deployed is here: https://github.com/dimarzio/testlambdalog

The only thing what is different - I'm using the shadowJar plugin...
Interesting thing is - when I look into the *all.jar the log4j2.xml is placed directly in the root of the *.jar

Answer (score 2):

I found the root of the problem and it was actually the shadowJar plugin! The files and folders structure that will be generated inside of the executable jar archive ist not completely recognisable by lambda execution environment.

To make it work (if you are using gradle) read this documentation site: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

The key is the buildZip gradle task.

So the use of shadowJar plugin for AWS Lambda provisioning must be treated with caution. Generally is works fine, but one can be confronted with problems I have updated the Github repo accordingly.